# Estructura proyecto SocketIo

Tags: socket, socket.io, websocket

Estoy empezando hacer la estructura para un proyecto hecho en socket.io, he realizado un ejemplo pero no me convence por los 2 eventos connect.

**Cliente:**

Envio el namespace al cual se conecta el cliente.

```
    <script>
      const socket = io('ws://localhost:3000/chat', {
        transports: ['websocket'],
        query: {
            namespace: "chat"
        }
      });

      socket.emit('send-message','Este es el mensaje a enviar');
    </script>
```

**Servidor:**

La función `chatService.sendMessage` tiene toda la logica para enviar el mensaje.

```js
    const Server = require('socket.io');
    const chatService = require('./functions/chat/service');

    //Run server
    const io = new Server(3000, {
        transports: ['websocket'],
        serveClient: false
    });

    io.on('connect', (socket) => {

        let resource = socket.handshake.query.namespace;
        //Evento de conexión al namespace
        io.of(resource).on('connect', (socket) => {
            //Ejecuto una función dependiendo del namespace y del evento recibido
            switch(resource){
                case "chat":
                    socket.on('send-message', async (data) => {
                        await chatService.sendMessage(io, socket, data);
                    });
                    socket.on('update-message', async (data) => {
                        await chatService.updateMessage(io, socket, data);
                    });
                    break;
            }
        });

    });
```

¿Alguien tiene un ejemplo mejor de una posible estructura?